# What's the relationship between vector and list in Lisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I was told that there are only atom and list as the basic data structure in Lisp, does this mean vector in Lisp is some type of list? Was vector stored as list in the underlying?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you were told was *accurate* but might not have been the *clearest* description.

In Common Lisp, at least:

```
* (type-of #(3 4 5))
(SIMPLE-VECTOR 3)

* (atom #(3 4 5))
T
```

An [atom is defined](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw60/CLHS/Body/f_atom.htm) as anything which is not a CONS cell -- including vectors, class instances, and so on.  So yes, a vector is officially considered an "atom" in Lisp, which is why you were told what you were told.

Comment: I would not have expected that. Emacs lisp has the same behavior: `(atom [1 2])` yields `t`. Scheme does not define a test for atom, but Chez Scheme's `(atom? obj)` is defined the same way, as equivelent to `(not (pair? obj))`. So it's not just Common Lisp that sees the world that way.

Comment: Whaddya know.  Good catch.  That'll teach me to read the docs before I tell others to.  I withdraw my answer.

Answer (score 2):

As everywhere else `vector` is structure for efficient random access, usually wrapper around array with some extras (auto grow). List is best for sequentical access and fast insertion.

Comment: Interesting, Common Lisp has `vector-push-extend` which does the auto-growing part. In Scheme, vectors are one-dimensional arrays, and they are fixed-sized; you get to do the growing yourself!